# gzip or not gzip

Tags: php, gzip

I keep hearing that gzip your site is a good practice to speed-up delivery. My site has a very vast load in general, shall i still look into gzip? I also read about disadvantages of using gzip, such as time required to unzip contents for the browser to display. Is it true?

---

UPDATE:

This question is based on the assumption that the site is fairly optimized already.

Actually I optimized it already. Most of the content on my site is db driven and originally it took some time to load it all, so what I did, I wrote a few scripts that run nightly, generate content and store it as static HTML files that are included on the heaviest trafficked pages. The load on the server is way below its capacity, so, thank you for that insight, I will consider it more seriously now. I was thinking of using some PHP class that does it dynamically. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: please read this : http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

Comment: You may also want to look into caching if it becomes a problem.

Comment: Chances are that content compression is already active on your server

Comment: Any modern computer can unzip/zip a file in very little time. Network transfers account for most (~95%) of the time taken to load a page. Combine javascript files and css, minify and gzip. This means fewer files (http requests) and smaller files which results in quicker page loads. Of course if your server is generating the pages slowly this won't much much difference. I'm sure it's all in the yahoo article mentioned above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Compressing your response will help with transfer times.  That means it will decrease the time it will take for the user to download the generated page.  It will not (in general) reduce the load on your server.  In fact, it can increase it slightly since compression itself is not free (it eats up some CPU cycles).

Typically, there's no disadvantage from a user experience (only advantages).

However, if your server is already heavily loaded, I'd probably skip it since it will only add to that load (in general).  Optimize the code first, then add compression.  Don't try to add compression as a band-aid for poorly optimized code (it won't work)...

Comment: *Optimize the code first, then add compression.* - I beg to differ. Optimization is a time-consuming (=expensive) task which doesn't necessarily give desired results. Gzipping is a simple measure which only costs you about half an hour of configuring your server and then some CPU cycles for guaranteed results. Even for high-load sites, I'd say the reduced bandwidth is well worth any CPU cost (I/O is slower than CPU).

Comment: @gustafc: Fair enough.  But the thing to realize is that it's not free.  And with modern Linux kernels and asynchronous I/O provided by most modern web servers is quite efficient (in terms of CPU cost for longer transfers).  Sure, there will be some gain by adding compression, but it depends on your loading whether it's going to help (If you're CPU bound, it'll likely hurt you to compress.  If you're disk or I/O bound, it'll help).  It all depends what state your CPUs sit in most of the time...

Comment: I would suggest either using [mod_deflate](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/) (if you're using Apache) or PHP's built in [ZLib Output Compression](http://us.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression).  They do a lot of checks for supported browsers, etc.  There's no real need to do it in PHP if you don't have to (meaning if you can edit a `.htaccess` file, or `php.ini`)...

Comment: Thanks, I'll check these. Yes I have full access to all files on my dedicated server.

Comment: @ircmaxwell - *If you're CPU bound, it'll likely hurt you to compress.* Yeah, sure, but when did you last run across a CPU bound web application?

Comment: @gustafc: More often than you'd think.  Usually due to bad SQL queries (Cartesian joins typically) or tight loops that don't need to be there.  It's especially common on budget hosts that use commodity processors (Centron/Centrino and Sempron processors) instead of server grade hardware...

Comment: I think the major point is that if you add compression as a band-aid, you better start optimizing that code immediately after (apply pressure to wound - get to hospital immediately).

Comment: Regarding CPU utilization and compression, I just wanted to add that compression is typically not an all or nothing feature. With Apache's mod_deflate, for example, you can set the effort level low if you think you might be bounded by the CPU, and still get a pretty decent compression ratio for certain types of files. Just something to be aware of for the readers who may not know their options.

Answer (score 10):

You should gzip your content because:

- it easy very [easy](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/speed-up-apache-20-web-access-or-downloads-with-mod_deflate.html) to do.
- it saves you bandwidth(which could save you money).
- it will make your site faster. You are right about that it takes a little bit time to unpack gzip, but still it is going to be faster because less data has to be downloaded.

You should also read the part about [gzip](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) from yahoo's best practices.

Comment: with a price . CPU consumption

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ircmaxell. You should try to optimize your app - if the database is poorly optimized or there are silly queries it will not do any magic for you. On the contrary you can not loose anything - the CPU will suffer from some additional load but it could severely decrease you bandwidth usage. Due to most modern browsers support GZIP compression it is only about the server asking client whether his browser support it. More info http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

Maybe you should also try to use it with some of the caching modules as suggested @Andrew Sledge. Try APC :-) http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php. Also try to compress css files, images or js files. I used to generating the whole web statically and then updated only changed pages - it definitely depends on the update rate..

Comment: Technical point. The server does not ask the client whether the client supports http response-entity compression. The client will instruct the server, in the `Accept-Encoding` header of each http request, which encoding/compression schemes the client supports and in which order of preference, and the server will use that information to determine which, if any, encoding/compression scheme to use to encode/compress the http response-entity.

Comment: @Justice: According to [HTTP 1.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), `If no Accept-Encoding field is present in a request, the server MAY assume that the client will accept any content coding`...  But if the header is present, it should be respected...

Comment: @ircmaxell, you are right, that is the spec. Of course, if I were charged with writing the spec, and if I didn't care about backward-compatibility with HTTP/1.0 and compatibility with existing implementations, my rule would be different. But I'm not, so it isn't.

Comment: @Justice: You have no argument from me.  I was just pointing out that if the header isn't there you are technically free to do what you wish.  But you are correct that you should respect it if it exists (which is why I recommend using a built in mechanism so that you don't need to worry about it)...

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is an old stack question, but figured I'd try to answer your question in today's terms / best practices.

Since you are making static files nightly I'd suggest looking into [zopfli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zopfli) compression of the static files [here's the php lib](https://github.com/clickalicious/php_zopfli). Particularly because zopfli compression is about 5% more compression than standard gzip, and it doesn't need to be done each time (you do it once when the static file is generated and store it that way). Then you can serve up the gziped file when requested by users that support gzip (you don't need on the fly compression that way). For the users that don't support gzip you can [gunzip](http://www.innerjoin.org/apache-compression/howto.html) it on your server (this reduces I/O since the zipped file is smaller than the unzipped version, essentially its on the fly decompression).

You should still use on the fly compression for dynamic content though (not zopfli, because it has a higher time / cost).

As far as time cost is concerned with regards to zopfli zipping the static content: As long as it is accessed more than 100 times a day it is worth doing, since it takes about 100x more processing power than standard gzip. So once you hit 101 your processor will have officially done less processing than on the fly compression of it.

Answer (score 0):

Time required to unzip the content is alway fraction to what you will save with transfer time.

1. GZip compression
2. Minify javascript, css and html
3. Reduce request by combining the files

Combined all three and you can will get much faster page load speeds. More details on this [here](https://medium.com/@nadeem.manzoor0/speed-up-your-website-868f14882fe7#.kg1upkgzw)